# Regex need to consider for all patterns in same group

Tags: python, regex, pyspark

Regex need to consider two patterns in same group

sample data ::

1. `mixexecutor:check_atom_exists:740 - requested to check this machine : **ET_colBackDDW_Temp**`
2. `output_of_reports/PII/36478_**ABP_BAL_liquidpressure**-**20210831-123456**-**20210831-172355**.bat.yz`
3. `packofexecutors:_to_signle_que:869-no mata for file'/private/external_control_time_mapped_low_volume/IBA/54378_BD-**RT_69-1**-1-**20200831-152355**-**20200831-172355**.dat.xz'`

4.`packofexecutors:_to_signle_que:869-no mata for file'/private/external_control_time_mapped_low_volume/IBA/54378_BD-**RT_69**-1-**20200831-152355**-**20200831-172355**.dat.xz'`

5.`mixexecutor:check_atom_exists:740 - requested to check this machine : **Eanes_colBack12_current**`

6.`packofexecutors._check_tar.587-nr of missed files=78 nr of skipped records=6547 nr of records not exist=0`

7.`packofexecutors._filter_mistacl_signals:777 - invalid atomname for **RT_6**:ESmotormeaninfAmkl`

Both the data belongs to same column need to identity highlighted values

Expected output:

1. `**ET_colBackDDW_Temp**`   --> group 1
2. `**ABP_BAL_liquidpressure**` --> group 1, `20210831-123456` --> group 2, `20210831-172355` --> group 3

3.`**RT_69-1**`--> group 1 ,`20200831-152355` --> group 2, `20200831-172355` --> group 3

4.`**RT_69**` --> group 1 , `20200831-152355` --> group 2, `20200831-172355` --> group 3

5.`**Eanes_colBack12_current**` --> group 1

6.None

7.`**RT_6**`

I have tried like below while developing the regex no need to consider the words

```
(^.*?((?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+_)+[A-Z]\w+)(?:-[0-9]{1,7})?)-([0-9]{8}-[0-9]{6})-([0-9]{8}-[0-9]{6}))?)
```

I am using PySpark to parse above regex

find below
https://regex101.com/r/yEBUxX/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the values in 1 or 3 groups using a single pattern, you might use:

```
^.*?([A-Z]\w*_\w+)(?:-([0-9]{8}-[0-9]{6})-([0-9]{8}-[0-9]{6}))?
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `.*?` Match as least a possible chars
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[A-Z]\w*_` Match A-Z and optional word chars and `_`
  - `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `-` Match literally
  - `([0-9]{8}-[0-9]{6})` Capture **group 2**
  - `-` match `-`
  - `([0-9]{8}-[0-9]{6})` Capture **group 3**
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UV7Vr7/1)

Comment: @shaa Like this? https://regex101.com/r/UV7Vr7/1